# Can I see a list of gyms I left a pokemon at?

Tags: pokemon-go

I captured a gym today just before the servers went down. I am wondering if I lost my progress. Is there a way to see if I own a gym or not?

Comment: Do you mean gyms owned by your team or gyms where you've left Pokémon?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer latter - gyms where I left pokemom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of today, there is *finally* a way to see what gyms you have Pokémon occupying!

If you go to your trainer profile after visiting gyms, there will be a list of gym badges you've earned. There is an indicator next to the gyms that currently have one of your Pokémon occupying it:

[image: gym badges]

If you tap on this gym badge, it will show what Pokémon you have defending that gym as well as how long that Pokémon has been defending the gym for.

[image: vaporeon in a gym]

Comment: Just FYI: If you want to keep your location secret (I assume so as you blacked out the name of city), I'd recommend blacking out all pokestop names as they can be used to determine your location too.

Comment: @Avery I was being lazy.

Answer (score 11):

If you keep personal track of which Pokemon you left where, then yes. The game shows a colored icon above one of your Pokemon if it's at a gym, but not which gym it is. You could also monitor which Pokemon you have at 1hp. Additionally, the icon in the top-right of the Shop (which you use to claim rewards for holding gyms) tells you the number of gyms you control.

Comment: Not necessarily blue, but your team color.

Answer (score 7):

A good little trick is rename your pokemon with the gyms location.

Change:

"Ponyta" to "Town Hall"
"Rhydon" to "College University"
"Rattata" to "University Cafe"

This way when a gym you own is taken down, you know which one it is.

Comment: Heh, nice idea man. Will do that once I get back to a place with Gyms... or pokemons for that matter :(

Answer (score 1):

You can see in your Pokemon screen which of your pokemon are assigned to a gym. They will have the gym symbol over the image of the pokemon.
That's the best you'll get as there's currently no way to see occupied gyms.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for "defender" in your Pokemon search will show a list of all defending Pokemon, which effectively shows which gyms you've left Pokemon at.