# What gym is my Pokémon in?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have some Pokémon that have been in gyms for a while. I do not remember which Pokémon is in which gym. This is different from previous questions, because I know I have Pokémon in gyms. What I want to know is, how can I find out which gyms which Pokémon are in?

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273157/can-i-see-a-list-of-gyms-i-left-a-pokemon-at, but from that question's title alone it _sounds_ like a duplicate; however, the actual question asked is different than the titular question.

Comment: There are a couple of minor reasons I can see why OP would want to know this information. There's no way in-game to determine what gym your Pokémon is at EXCEPT by stumbling upon the gym and inspecting it where you can see trainer names. There are various websites that can tell you this information also, but again, you'd need to actually select each gym and find your name. I use https://gymhuntr.com/, and have no affiliation with the website. This site won't help if you have ZERO recollection of where your Pokémon are

Comment: @Tas That's a pretty slick site, a little stale but will work for my needs.